# Is there a way to create a new branch on a Google Cloud Source Repositories repo using the Python SDK?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Cloud Source Repositories to store code for my CI/CD pipeline. What I'm building has two repos: `core` and `clients`. The `core` code will be built and deployed to monitor changes to a cloud storage bucket. When it detects a new customer config in the bucket, it will copy the `clients` code into a new branch of the `clients` repo named after the customer. The idea is to enable later potential tailoring for a given customer beyond the standard `clients` codebase.

The solution I've been considering is to have the `core` deploy programmatically create the branches in the the `clients` repo, but have come up empty handed in my research for how to do that in Google Cloud.

The only documentation that is close to what I want to do is [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/apis).

Comment: The API in your question is for managing repositories and not the contents of the repository.  Use a git compatible library or API. I have not used this library but this is an example of many: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: That makes obvious sense - thanks!

Comment: @Dshiz, did the previous comment address your concern? If so, please post it as an answer so that it would be helpful for other community members with similar questions such as yours.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Cloud SDKs do not provide a git API. However, there are python libraries that integrate with git like [gitpython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable) as one example.

Credit goes to @JohnHanley for his comment to my question for this answer.